# Selenium is unable to locate input fields on payment form

Tags: forms, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

I have a Selenium bot that automates the process of submitting a SoundCloud URL to a playlist curator platform. However, I am encountering an issue where the web driver can locate the 'confirm payment' button in the form but is unable to input data into the payment card fields. I am using Selenium 4 with the Firefox web driver.                 Here are the locators and strings I am using:

```
cardNum='0000111122223333'

cvv_Input = '//*[@id="cvv"]'

CVV = '123'

exp_Date_Input = '//*[@id="expiration"]'

expDate = '01/01/2029'

zipCodeInput = '//*[@id="postal-code"]'

zipCode = '22010'
```

[image: Payment Automation]